# Need to read the user id and password from properties file in ANT build script while executing SOAPUI test execution

Tags: ant, soapui

I have a ANT build script and a properties file. I want the build script should read the user id and password from properties file and the SOAP request runs using these credentials. Please help how to do it.

My Properties file is given below:

```
element.name=PC
user.name=XXX
user.password=YYY
domain.name=ZZZ
machine.name=ZZZ
machine.port=8080
soapuiproject.list=abc.xml;def.xml;
```

The section of the Build script that reads the above properties, is given below:

```
`<for list="${soapuiproject.list}" param="soapui-project" delimiter=";">
                    <sequential>
                            <echo>excuting soapui project @{soapui-project}</echo>
     <exec executable="${env.SOAPUI_HOME}/bin/testrunner.sh"  osfamily="unix" failonerror="false">
      <arg value="-j" />
      <arg value="-r" />
      <arg value="-I" />
      <arg value="-a"/>
      <arg value="-u${user.name}" />
      <arg value="-p${user.password}" />
      <arg value="-d${domain.name}" />
      <arg value="-f/opt/jenkins/workspace/soapui-reports/${folderstamp}" />
      <arg value="-Pmachine.name=${machine.name}"/>
      <arg value="-Pmachine.port=${machine.port}" />
      <arg value="${basedir}/src/@{soapui-project}" />
    </exec>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a line above the for loop

```
<property file="file.properties"/>
```

please provide your findings, if it didn't work. happy to help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It didn't work. We have teh following tags to read the properties file:<property file="${basedir}/soapuiInputs_Kolps47.properties" />

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It didn't work. We have the following tags to read the properties file:<project name="buildAutoamtionForOrga" default="test" basedir=".">
        <property environment="env" />
        <property file="${basedir}/soapuiInputs.properties" />
  
  
The corresponding build script is able to replace the web service endpoint etc by reading this property file but cannot replace the userid and password in the SOAP request as per the properties file.

Comment: Any idea regarding the above issue?

Comment: its argument/attribute hence you need to use @{user.name}  not ${user.name}  I hope this works, if not please provide your finding. we solve this

Comment: No again it dint work...As suggested by you I have made following changes in properties and build.xml file:

element.name=PC
soapui.user.name=abc
soapui.user.password=def
domain.name=kolps47

The Build script has been changed accordingly:

<exec executable="${env.SOAPUI_HOME}/bin/testrunner.sh"  osfamily="unix" failonerror="false">
 <arg value="-j" />
<arg value="-r" />
 <arg value="-I" />
<arg value="-a"/>
<arg value="-u@{soapui.user.name}" />
<arg value="-p@{soapui.user.password}" />
<arg value="-d${domain.name}" />

Comment: Ok . have you tried printing echo of each properties before sending it to <exec> are you able to print them

Comment: i mean <echo message="*** ${soapui.user.name}****"/>    are you able to get this before sending it to exec?

Comment: Yes...I have put a comment before execution <echo>${soapui.user.name}</echo>...it worked. But if I give <echo>@{soapui.user.name}</echo>...it doesnot work

Comment: Now the issue is <arg value="-u${soapui.user.name}" />  is not working right? if yes then could you please post me the actual command that is generating from this ant and executing the testRunner.sh from ant log.

Comment: Where to find the ant log? In my Unix system it is installed here:/usr/local/ant_test/apache-ant-1.9.5/. I have not found log. Please help.

Comment: it doesnt matter where ant installed as long as it is in PATH variable, I asked what happens when you execute like ant -f yourbuildfile i wanto see the output

Comment: ----------------- Properties ------------------------------
Encoding: UTF-8
Password: @{soapui.user.password}
Username: @{soapui.user.name}
domain: servername
Endpoint: http://<servername:8080/pcservice/pc.wsdl
---------------- Request ---------------------------
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-4">
<wsse:Username>abc</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">def</wsse:Password>

Comment: The user id and password in the request section does not match with the Username and Password in the properties file. Currently using the @ doesnot work here but if I use $ it reflects in the properties section correctly.

Comment: use ${soapui.user.password}  and ${soapui.user.name} only

Comment: Yes...from the very beginning it was there but it doesnot overwrite the userid and password in the request section.---------------- Request --------------------------- <soapenv:Header> <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-4"> <wsse:Username>abc</wsse:Username>...does not get overwritten by teh properties

Comment: Ok can you show me what is the reference name you kept in   <wsse:Username>${#Project#blah}</wsse:Username>

Comment: <wsse:Username>${#Project#user.name}</wsse:Username>

Comment: how it will over ride man ? you are sending it as a -uuser.name  and you are accessing -Puser.name  try changing -Puser.name=${soapui.user.name}   it will work for sure

Comment: Dont forgot click answered

Comment: I dint get it....the userid property is soapui.user.name=Test1 in soapuiInputs.properties file, ant build script reads the same : <arg value="-u${soapui.user.name}" />

Comment: After running of build script request log reads Properties section ----------------- Properties ------------------------------
Encoding: UTF-8
Username: Test1     But in Request it shows <wsse:Username>ABC</wsse:Username>

Comment: <wsse:Username>${#Project#user.name}</wsse:Username> #Project#user.name   from outside will refer to -Puser.name which is a project level property all project level properties  you have to pass like -Pkey=value  by the way do you have custom property "user.name" at the project level

Comment: That's right...it worked.:) Thank you very much Suman for your help. Outstanding discussion here and got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just load your properties file using :

```
<property file="file.properties"/>
```